# Wpf multiline textbox style that affects the individual lines

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, styles

I need to make a multi line textbox that changes the back ground for charaters after the line becomes longer than 80 characters. So that if someone types a sentence of 85 characters the last 5 characters will have a yellow background. I would like it to make this feature part of the style because currently we are tying to do this with logic in the code behind and it lags when someone types quickly.

current highlighting imlp

```
 private void HighlightLines()
        {
            try
            {
                //// x is the distance in the row from the left side of the Textbox. e.g. Each character is one unit.
                int x = 0;
                //// y is the distance in the columns from the top of the Textbox. e.g. Each character is one unit.
                int y = 0;
                //// lines is the number of newline characters found in the Text.
                int lines = 0;
                //// Point 1 is the starting point of the range that needs to be highlighted.
                TextPointer point1 = this.Document.ContentStart;
                //// Point 2 is the end point of the range that needs to be highlighted.
                TextPointer point2 = this.Document.ContentStart;
                //// Range is the distance from Point 1 to Point 2 needed to apply the Yellow color to the area past 69 characters.
                TextRange range;
                //// Additional Ranges is the collection of all the ranges that need to be Yellow.
                this.AdditionalRanges = new ObservableCollection<TextRange>();

                //// Count the number of lines.
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Text.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (this.Text[i] == '\n')
                    {
                        lines++;
                        this.AdditionalRanges.Add(new TextRange(this.Document.ContentStart, this.Document.ContentEnd));
                    }
                }
                //// This map is used to differentiate which lines need to be colored. (True means the range is over 69 characters. False means the opposite).
                bool[] map = new bool[lines];

                //// Traverse the whole text.
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Text.Length; i++)
                {
                    var currentCharacter = this.Text[i];
                    var newLineCharacter = '\n';

                    if (currentCharacter == newLineCharacter)
                    {
                        var pointDifference = point1.GetOffsetToPosition(point2);
                        point1 = point1.GetPositionAtOffset(pointDifference);
                        x = 0;
                        y++;
                    }
                    else if (x > 69)
                    {
                        range = new TextRange(point1, point2);
                        this.AdditionalRanges[y] = range;
                        map[y] = true;
                        if (point2.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward) != null)
                        {
                            point2 = point2.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (point1.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward) != null && point2.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward) != null)
                    {
                        point1 = point1.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        point2 = point2.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        x++;
                    }
                }

                //// Make everything white.
                foreach (var item in this.AdditionalRanges)
                {
                    item.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White);
                }

                //// Make the appropriate ranges Yellow.
                for (int i = 0; i < this.AdditionalRanges.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (map[i])
                    {
                        this.AdditionalRanges[i].ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // drop exception. this has only broke once and we dont exactly know why. 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think this is something you can do in XAML alone. Can you post your code-behind logic so we can see your current approach?

Comment: You could do this with custom syntax highlighting in AvalonEdit (available as a NuGet package), but that might be overkill. How much text do you need to handle at once?

Comment: its for the military so we cant use anything outside of unapproved packages and it is a hassle to get new sources approved.

Comment: I added out highlighting function if anyone wants to help improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably lagging because your `HighlightLines()` method is scanning the entire document every time, and I assume it gets called after every keypress. Ideally you want to only re-scan the portions of the text that have changed. Fortunately, the TextChanged event provides the exact offset of the changes.

The example code below was written to work with a RichTextBox but you should be able to adapt it. Also, it looks like your code was checking for 69 characters instead of 80, so this does the same:

```
RichTextBox txt;
...
bool suppressChanges = false;
private void Txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!suppressChanges)
    {
        // suppress changes because changing highlights will trigger the event again
        suppressChanges = true;
        foreach (var change in e.Changes)
        {
            var changeStart = txt.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset);
            TextRange changedRange;
            if (change.AddedLength > 0)
                changedRange = new TextRange(changeStart, changeStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.AddedLength));
            else
                changedRange = new TextRange(changeStart, changeStart);
            SetRangeColors(changedRange);
        }

        //unsuppress changes
        suppressChanges = false;
    }
}

void SetRangeColors(TextRange range)
{
    // Scan one line at a time starting with the beginning of the range
    TextPointer current = range.Start.GetLineStartPosition(0);
    while (current != null && current.CompareTo(range.End) < 0)
    {
        // find the next line or the end of the document
        var nextLine = current.GetLineStartPosition(1, out int lines);
        TextPointer lineEnd;
        if (lines > 0)
            lineEnd = nextLine.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
        else
            lineEnd = txt.Document.ContentEnd;
        var lineRange = new TextRange(current, lineEnd);

        // clear properties first or the offsets won't match the characters
        lineRange.ClearAllProperties();
        var lineText = lineRange.Text;
        if (lineText.Length > 69)
        {
            var highlight = new TextRange(current.GetPositionAtOffset(70), lineEnd);
            highlight.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
        }

        // advance to the next line
        current = lineEnd.GetLineStartPosition(1);
    }
}
```